# MOSFET load line - VGS above VDD?

Tags: mosfet

I am currently learning about mosfets and was looking to get some intuitive guidance on the load line on a typical MOSFET curve.

I am using this very helpful and intuitive lecture slides from http://aries.ucsd.edu/NAJMABADI/CLASS/ECE102/11-F/NOTES/ECE102_F11-LecSet-2.pdf . However I am little confused by what happens if you increase VGS above VDD. The line continues into an area that is not bounded by the load line.

- Does the MOSFET break?
- or is there some equation that governs it's Vds and iD at these given values for Vgs?
- Is there an equation for this behaviour?

[image]

Comment: It's fine as long as it's below the Abs Max Vgs.

Answer (score 2):

The instructor made what is -- in my opinion -- a poor choice of voltages to use in his example.  In a MOSFET there's real constraints on \$v_{gs}\$ that pertain to \$V_{DD}\$, or even to \$v_d\$.  The situation's different for a JFET -- but we're not talking about JFETs here.

Each of the traces in the set of characteristic curves for the MOSFET (the plot on the left) are a function of the drain voltage (\$v_d\$), the characteristics of the FET, and the gate-source voltage (\$v_{gs}\$).  They have *nothing at all to do with whatever \$V_{DD}\$ may happen to be*.

In fact, \$V_{DD}\$ is just the voltage of the drain *supply*.  The FET does not "know" what it is -- the FET only responds to the voltages and currents on its pins.

> Does the MOSFET break?

There is a maximum \$v_{gs}\$ value.  It's typically around 20V for most power MOSFETs today (RF MOSFETS may be wimpier).  But it has nothing directly to do with \$V_{DD}\$.

> or is there some equation that governs it's Vds and iD at these given values for Vgs?
> Is there an equation for this behaviour?

Yes and no.  With a set \$v_{gs}\$, the drain and source terminal pair act like any other two-terminal device; i.e., there's a fixed relationship between \$v_{ds}\$ and the drain (and source) current.  You can **never** control voltage and current independently on a two-terminal device of fixed characteristics.

Having said that, there most certainly are equations that describe how \$i_d\$ will behave as a function of \$v_{ds}\$ and \$v_{gs}\$.  The easiest place that I can point you to is Wikipedia, but it's in innumerable circuit design textbooks (usually starting with 2nd- or 3rd- year circuit design; it's been long enough I can't remember which one!!).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET#Modes_of_operation

Answer (score 0):

Nothing unusual happens unless you exceed the breakdown voltage for Vgs (some MOSFETs have internal zener diodes to protect the gate insulation, and without that at some point the thin insulating layer fails and the MOSFET is kaput).

Vdd is an arbitrary supply voltage in this case, and we are assuming there is a resistor between the drain and Vdd for the given load line to be valid.

So you can draw additional curves for Vgs higher than Vdd in the right-hand graph and the load line would intersect at an ever narrower region near Vds = 0 (which makes sense since you have a fixed resistor load to a fixed voltage and you are enhancing the MOSFET conduction more and more).

It's not unusual to have situations where a MOSFET is switched with 5V or 12V on the gate and is switching high current at a lower voltage such as a few volts or less.